# ASCI characters change in Matlab when switching between Windows, Macintosh and Linux

Tags: matlab, github, version-control, ascii

I am maintaining a Github repository with Matlab source code. I happen to live in a country with a slightly eccentric alphabet - we have the letters 'å', 'ä' and 'ö' at the end. However comments in my eccentric language sometimes change from this:

```
% Instruktioner:
% 1. Skriv 'h = Eeg' i kommandoprompten (en gång)
%       Välj vilken *_sc.mat fil som skall användas
```

to this:

```
% Instruktioner:
% 1. Skriv 'h = Eeg' i kommandoprompten (en gï¿½g)
%       Vï¿½j vilken *_sc.mat fil som skall anvï¿½das
```

The problem also occurs from time to time with the symbol '¤' in code sections.

The only text editor I use to edit the files is Matlab's built-in text editor, and the code is regularly edited and uploaded on Mac, Linux and Windows machines (in case it is a feature of one of the operating systems).

It does not happen all the time, otherwise it would have been easier to track down.

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: In older versions of MATLAB (dont remember which , but I assume about 2012) I had a problem working with a friend on linux and myself on windows. Whenever he would wrote something out of the ASCII table, my windows MATLAB would replace it by something weird. We were not using github. Check that just in case.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! It appears to be the switch between Windows and Linux after all, updating the question accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this in a matlab prompt, this is te example for my linux (in catalan)

```
>> feature('DefaultCharacterSet')
feature('locale')

ans =

UTF-8


ans = 

               ctype: 'ca_ES.UTF-8'
             collate: 'ca_ES.UTF-8'
                time: 'ca_ES.UTF-8'
             numeric: 'en_US_POSIX.UTF-8'
            monetary: 'ca_ES.UTF-8'
            messages: 'ca_ES.UTF-8'
            encoding: 'UTF-8'
    terminalEncoding: 'UTF-8'
         jvmEncoding: 'UTF-8'
              status: 'MathWorks locale management system initialized.'
             warning: ''
```

From [Matlab works](https://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/238995)

1. Fire up a fresh Matlab session.
2. Type feature('DefaultCharacterSet','UTF8').
3. Follow up with feature('DefaultCharacterSet'). This should return UTF-8 in the command window.
4. Check accented characters with char() command.
5. Add lines in 2 and 3 into your startup.m.
6. Now Matlab will start up into UTF-8 under Linux 64bit every time.